# Python regex to parse contents of sudoers log that spans accross multiple lines

Tags: regex, python-2.7, sudo

I would need to extract date, user and command executed from a few hundred sudo.log files. 
the problem is that the sudo log entries are spaned across multiple lines and the command can have multiple lines.

an example of a entries in sudoers is like this:

```
Aug  7 14:14:43 : user1 : TTY=pts/53 ; PWD=/path2 ;
    USER=root ; COMMAND=/path/to/cmd1
Aug  7 14:14:49 : user2 : TTY=pts/53 ; PWD=/usr/home ;
    USER=root ; COMMAND=./myscript.sh -m name -o SCHEDULER
Aug  7 14:15:14 : user3 : TTY=pts/34 ;
    PWD=/path ; USER=root ;
    COMMAND=/usr/bin/egrep ^[a-z]*
    /filename/toto1234
Aug  7 14:15:37 : user4 : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/opt/nagios ; USER=root ;
    COMMAND=/path/to/less
    /var/opt/otherfile
Aug  7 14:16:04 : user4 : TTY=pts/34 ;
    PWD=/usr/local/bin/script ; USER=root ;
    COMMAND=/usr/bin/egrep ^[a-z]*
    /user/local/sbin/tata
```

What a have noticed is each entry of the sudoers start with the date. followed by a colon then the user and then on other line the command exectuted. I would like to capture the date, user and command..

I think i should capture everything comming after COMMAND until the date is found again?

I have this regx that capture the date and username because they tend to be on the same line but don't know how capture the COMMAND

this is what I have so far:

```
(^\w{3}\s+\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+)\s?:\s?(\w+?)\s+:.*
```

i have been testing it here:

https://regex101.com/r/qFnv0t/2/

my idea is perhaps for the command capture everything until group1 is matches again? or first i  need to modify the log files and make one entry per line?

thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of a capturing group and first match all the lines the do not contain COMMAND.

Then match from after COMMAND until the first line that starts with a "date like" pattern.

You don't have to make matching the word characters non greedy `\w+?` using questionmark.

```
^(\w{3}\s+\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+)\s?:\s?(\w+)\s+:.*(?:\r?\n(?!.*COMMAND).*)*\r?\n.*?COMMAND=(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\w{3}\s+\d+\s\d+).*)*)
```

*About the pattern*

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w{3}\s+\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+` Match date like format
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s?:\s?` Match `:` surrounded by optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `)` Close group 2
- `\s+:.*` Match 1+ whitespace chars, `:` and 0+ times any char except a newline
- `(?:` Non capturing group
- `\r?\n(?!.*COMMAND).*` Match newline, assert that the line does not contain COMMAND. Then match 0+ times any char except a newline
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `\r?\n.*?COMMAND=` Match newline until the first occurrence of `COMMAND=`
- `(` Capture **group 3**

  - `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\r?\n(?!\w{3}\s+\d+\s\d+).*` Match newline, assert that the line does not start with a date like pattern, then match the rest of the line
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times as the command can span multiple lines
- `)` Close group 3

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ktffc4/1) | [Python example](https://ideone.com/TqNSIs)

Note that the datelike format does not validate a date itself.

Comment: how would I need to open the file in python because even if the regex works as expected when I open the file only one line is found and it return a list with one line.

Comment: @zn553 You have to enable multiline mode. Can you load the whole file as a string? For example using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) https://ideone.com/TqNSIs

Comment: that was it I was compiling the regex with `re.M+re.S+re.I` but somehow it was not working. I open the file like this: `sudo_log=file(r'/var/log/sudo.log').read()`